# What is the probability that X takes even values?

Tags: probability

Am trying to show that the probability a count r.v $X$ takes even values is given by

$\frac 1 2( 1 + G(-1)),$ where $G(t)$ is its probability generating function.

I know that due to possible symmetry then the $P(\text{odd}) + P(\text{even}) =1.$

Kindly help any initial stages.

Answer (score 0):

$$
G(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \Pr(X=n).
$$
$$
G(-1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \Pr(X=n).
$$
\begin{align}
& 1 + G(-1) \\[10pt] = {} & \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1\Pr(X=n)\right) + \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \Pr(X=n) \right) & & \text{since the first sum is 1} \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Big( 1 + (-1)^n\Big) \Pr(X=n).
\end{align}
Then observe that $\displaystyle 1+(-1)^n = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if $n$ is even,} \\ 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd.} \end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you, now I see the use of 1/2.